# Get Same Signature using PHP

Tags: php

hello following is the code in .net or java i do not know exactly but it is generating a signature how can i get same signature by adding same values using php

```
long timestamp = 1499084258;
String nonce= "37822614634975090106662";
String httpMethod = "GET"; // HTTP Method of the resource that is being called
String encodedResourceUrl = "https://sandbox.interswitchng.com/api/v2/quickteller/categorys"; // put the resource URL here
String clientId = "IKIA9D981C53698A71925002C81E09104959B975G5C41E1"; // put your client Id here
String clientSecretKey = "d5uAr+U8QhSvYu0809vQtKop3kRslRBC5Q+SwIt+/r4nk+y0="; // put your client secret here
String signatureCipher = httpMethod + "&" + encodedResourceUrl + "&" + timestamp + "&" + nonce + "&" + clientId + "&" + clientSecretKey;
MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(signatureMethod);
byte[] signatureBytes = messageDigest.digest(signatureCipher.getBytes());
String signature = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(signatureBytes));

signature = bqqFzzDe8jJOwjR9/0cY8Lh3Uik=
```

i want to get same signature 'bqqFzzDe8jJOwjR9/0cY8Lh3Uik=' with php
i tried many methods with these values base 64, sha1 and both same time but it generates different from this signature

Comment: What is `MessageDigest.digest`? Also what is `signatureMethod`?

Comment: Request signature. Must be represented in base 64. The signature is calculated from a combination defined data elements separated by the '&' character.

Comment: and signtaureMethod is SHA1

Comment: The code above the following: 1) gets a set of data (httpMethod, clientId, clientSecretKey and encodedResourceUrl ) 2) concatenate them 3) Apply a hashing algorithm on them like sha1. 4) Convert the signature generated by hashing algorithm to Base64.

Comment: Please provide your PHP code. Also normally PHP hash function output hex and not bytes. Have you tried to convert hex to bytes and then apply base64 on them.

Comment: i tried this one but result is different

Comment: base64_encode(sha1($signatureCipher, true));

Comment: Please see my updated answer below and if I am correct which I am sure of, please award me the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***The correct answer***

You have a mistake somewhere as the result is not `"bqqFzzDe8jJOwjR9/0cY8Lh3Uik="`

I have just fired up my Java IDE and wrote the following code:

```
package com.company;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;

public class HashingExample {

    public void run() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");

        long timestamp = 1499084258;
        String nonce= "37822614634975090106662";
        String httpMethod = "GET"; // HTTP Method of the resource that is being called
        String encodedResourceUrl = "https://sandbox.interswitchng.com/api/v2/quickteller/categorys"; // put the resource URL here
        String clientId = "IKIA9D981C53698A71925002C81E09104959B975G5C41E1"; // put your client Id here
        String clientSecretKey = "d5uAr+U8QhSvYu0809vQtKop3kRslRBC5Q+SwIt+/r4nk+y0="; // put your client secret here
        String signatureCipher = httpMethod + "&" + encodedResourceUrl + "&" + timestamp + "&" + nonce + "&" + clientId + "&" + clientSecretKey;

        byte[] signatureBytes = md.digest(signatureCipher.getBytes());
        String signature = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(signatureBytes));

        System.out.print(signature);
    }
}
```

and run the code as follows:

```
package com.company;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashingExample hashingExample = new HashingExample();
        try {
            hashingExample.run();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
   }
}
```

**The output of the java code is**

> c1iTcvkG2zh5/jCWpsr/VlynCe4=

Then I switch to PHP and wrote the following code:

```
$timestamp = 1499084258;
$nonce = "37822614634975090106662";
$httpMethod = "GET"; // HTTP Method of the resource that is being called
$encodedResourceUrl = "https://sandbox.interswitchng.com/api/v2/quickteller/categorys"; // put the resource URL here
$clientId = "IKIA9D981C53698A71925002C81E09104959B975G5C41E1"; // put your client Id here
$clientSecretKey = "d5uAr+U8QhSvYu0809vQtKop3kRslRBC5Q+SwIt+/r4nk+y0="; // put your client secret here
$signatureCipher = $httpMethod . "&" . $encodedResourceUrl . "&" . $timestamp . "&" . $nonce . "&" . $clientId . "&" . $clientSecretKey;
$messageDigest = sha1($signatureCipher, true);

echo "\n";
echo "My hex: " . bin2hex($messageDigest);
echo "\n";
echo "My base64: " . base64_encode($messageDigest);
```

**And the output was**

```
//My hex: 73589372f906db3879fe3096a6caff565ca709ee
//My base64: c1iTcvkG2zh5/jCWpsr/VlynCe4=
```

> The two outputs are the same and there for you are doing something
>   wrong since `"bqqFzzDe8jJOwjR9/0cY8Lh3Uik="` cannot be the result of
>   the Java code.

---

***My Previous answer***

The code you posted is missing the variable called `nonce`

I have started by converting your result to HEX as follows:

```
echo bin2hex(base64_decode("bqqFzzDe8jJOwjR9/0cY8Lh3Uik="));
// result -> 6eaa85cf30def2324ec2347dff4718f0b8775229
```

Since we are missing the variable called `nonce` then it is impossible to get the same signature. However this is how I would do it:

```
$timestamp = 1499084258;

$httpMethod = "GET"; // HTTP Method of the resource that is being called
$encodedResourceUrl = "https://sandbox.interswitchng.com/api/v2/quickteller/categorys"; // put the resource URL here
$clientId = "IKIA9D981C53698A71925002C81E09104959B975G5C41E1"; // put your client Id here
$clientSecretKey = "d5uAr+U8QhSvYu0809vQtKop3kRslRBC5Q+SwIt+/r4nk+y0="; // put your client secret here

$signatureCipher = $httpMethod + "&" + $encodedResourceUrl + "&" + $timestamp + "&" + $nonce + "&" + $clientId + "&" + $clientSecretKey;

$messageDigest = hash('sha1', $signatureCipher);
// this will give a hex value. Without `nonce` we will get 
// 9edc77e0745da0f98b71251435c90cb51a4a8840

$bytes = hex2bin($messageDigest);

echo base64_encode($bytes);
```

**Again this has not been tested since we a variable is missing**

Comment: sorry my mistake this is nonce
37822614634975090106662